# Chef, override attribute

Tags: chef-infra

The default java version in [the chef java cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java) is version 6. How would you change that to version 7 using the override attributes?

```
$cat default.rb

 default['java']['jdk_version'] = '6'
 ...
```

According to the chef documentation, the basic syntax of an override looks like this:

[image]

Yet it is not clear how that maps to `default['java']['jdk_version']`
Here are the syntaxes that I have tried unsuccessfully.

```
{
  "node['java']['jdk_version']":"7"
}
```

---

```
{
  "jdk_version":"7"
}
```

---

```
{
  "default": {
    "java":{
      "jdk_version":"7"
     } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [precedence level](http://docs.chef.io/nodes.html#attribute-precedence) of the attribute is the `default` part (you see this in the screen reflected on the upper right side).

Therefore, the JSON content that you have to set should be:

```
{
  "java":{
    "jdk_version":"7"
  }
}
```